# SQL Service Broker 2012 queue has message_enqueue_time in GMT

Tags: sql, service-broker, gmt

It seems that message_enqueue_time in SQL Service Broker is in GMT rather than local time.

Is there any configuration that needs to be done to get this to show up in local time?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All times related to SQL Service Broker are expressed as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This is intentional and non configurable. Displaying local time in the application is trivial, use whatever your client framework offers for converting UTC to your local.

Comment: We put a view that uses a function to convert the UTC to local time considering daylight savings as well and it helps with our issue.